# Mocha says "ERROR: Unexpected token {" (using @babel/preset-env)

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, babeljs

I have installed "@babel/core": "^7.7.7", "@babel/preset-env": "^7.8.3", "@babel/preset-react": "^7.7.4", "@babel/register": "^7.8.3".

I'm running mocha with this line (via npm's run command):

```
mocha --require @babel/register --require ./test/helpers.js --require ./test/dom.js --require ignore-styles 'src/**/*.spec.js'
```

My .babelrc is as follows:

```
{
  presets: [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        "modules": "auto"
      }
    ],
    "@babel/preset-react"
  ]
}
```

All the issues I can find other people having on this are either old or a problem with their .babelrc or how they're calling on mocha. I've tried a number of variations and I can't tell what's triggering this. (I also don't have any sort of error stack or location for the "Unexpected token {".)

Anybody have any ideas?

Comment: I thought babelrc files are supposed to have JSON content? i.e. strings are eclosed in `"` not `'`

Comment: @Jaromanda X It doesn't seem to make any difference, and most of the babelrc file was a snippet I took from a tutorial. (I guess it wouldn't be *safe* to assume it worked for the tutorial writer, but I would hope he had it working before he posted it.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found similar issue:
https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/8477

Try changing your .babelrc into this instead. Since @babel/preset-env's module options is defaulted to "auto"(https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-env#modules)

```
{
   "presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"]
}
```

Comment: These things are so picky. :P Thanks. I'll remember to check back tomorrow when it will allow me to award a bounty.

Comment: Sure thing! Cheers!